# Extjs Ext.MessageBox

Tags: extjs, tooltip, messagebox

I am trying to add a tooltip(Ext.tip.ToolTip) to the title of the message box(Ext.MessageBox)

I am using

Ext.MessageBox.show(
{
title: 'Title',
subtitle: 'Subtitle',
message: 'Message'
});

How can I add an Ext.tip.ToolTip to the title of the Message Box?

Answer (score 0):

THis is for the modern toolkit.  May be similar for classic.

Ext.MessageBox has a header config.  This can be a config object.  The header is a Ext.panel.Header and this object has a tooltip config.